# Mapping of entities without tables

Tags: hibernate

we use hibernate in our project and it just came out that we would like to use the power of hibernate to work with entities that do not have table behind them.

Simplified situation looks like this. I have 3 tables CUSTOMER_ATTRIBUTES, CONTRACT_ATTRIBUTES, CUSTOMER_CONTRACT_RELATION. Both attributes tables have structure - id (either customer id or contract id), name, value (for each id, there could be more entries). The relation table contains mapping between customers and contracts (1 customer can have many contracts).

At the end I would like to have 2 entities. Customer (identified by customer id, and having collection of attributes) and Contract (identified by contract id, and having collection of attributes). And I would like to have them related using hibernate associations.

Is it possible to create such entities using some kind of hibernate mapping?

Comment: Just to be certain: You want to build an [Entity Attribute Value database design](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model)? Then it would be certain you will [run into a lot of problems](http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/Database-Changes-Done-Right.aspx). Using Hibernate because you want to use the power of Hibernate will not work; Hibernate works best with clean relational designs. When you need to use this design (legacy DB) I would drop the idea of utilizing Hibernate.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `@subselect` annotation in hibernate for mapping entity to query instead of table.
for more information have a look hibernate [doc](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/reference/en-US/html/mapping.html)